# Apache Shiro: dynamically enable/disable realm

Tags: java, shiro

The Java EE 8 web application can have several realms: one that is always enabled for internal user storage, another one for auth/author against AD (for example).

So, the realms list is the following:

1. Realm 1: LocalUserRealm extends AuthorizingRealm
2. Realm 2: ActiveDirectoryRealm (optional, should be enabled and configured via app by providing required settings: ldap url, usr, pwd, etc)

Currently, `shiro.ini` looks like the following:

```
[main]
...
localUserRealm = local.LocalUserRealm
...
adRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryRealm
...
securityManager.realms = $localUserRealm, $adRealm
```

The question: what is the best way to enable / disable the optional `adRealm` on the fly, after pressing buttons in the app like "enable AD integration" / "disable AD integration"?

1. Is it valid approach to add realm during runtime via `SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager().setRealms(realmsList)`?
2. What would be the best way of disabling / destroying the realm (or just use `SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager().setRealms(realmsList)` again by excluding the disabled realms)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call `getRealms()` (as listed above) before replacing them, get the delta of the list.  Call `setRealms(newList)`.  Then loop through the delta and check if the Realm was `Destroyable` if so, call `destroy()`.

Comment: Thank you for answering here as well! ;)

Comment: This is a bit old but since I had the same problem I'll add that for this to work you need to cast the `SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager()` from a `SecurityManager` to a `RealmSecurityManager`, [as the setRealm method is only available on the latter](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/mgt/RealmSecurityManager.html)